# How many pins does a PCI x4 connection needs in a FPGA?

Tags: fpga, pins, pcie

I am new to the FPGA world.
Reading the specs for variuos FPGAs I see there are lots of transceivers.
I have a number of PCIe x.4 devices.
How many pins and/or transceivers do I need to connect to one PCIe x4 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One transceiver per lane (four pins, differential TX and RX) plus a differential 100 MHz reference clock and the PCIe reset line. I think that's pretty much the minimum for a PCIe add-in card. If you're connecting to external PCIe devices as a root complex, the lane requirements are the same, but you'll need to provide reference clock and reset signals to all the devices, which can be done externally (clock buffers, etc.)